# loop over variables in dataframe R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Not completelty sure if my question is a duplicate...

Suppose I have a dataframe (X), containing 3 columns (A,B and C) with > 100 rows:

X:

```
A B C
5 10 20
10 8 100
...
```

Next, I want to use the values of each row (loop) in this dataframe in a script:

For example, in the first "loop"

```
A<-5
B<-10
C<-20
D<-A*B*C
```

The second loop

```
A<-10
B<-8
C<-100
D<-A*B*C
```

So in the end the ouput of my script contains two values

```
1000
8000
```

Anyone could help me with that?

Thank you in advance.

WD

Comment: Try `X$D <- apply(X, 1, prod)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `Reduce`

```
df$D <- Reduce(`*`, df)
```

Comment: THanks for the proposed solution. But I think I simplified my example too much. I would like to use the variables in each row to make a plot. So for n rows, I would like to make N plots (using the 3 variables).

Comment: @WannesDermauw  It is better to show something that related to what u r doing